# Pressing CAPSLOCK and a number in Hebrew mode no longer inserts nikkud

Tags: windows-10, hebrew, diacritics

I used to be able to insert diacritics (nikkud) in Hebrew by entering Hebrew language mode, pressing caps lock, and then the shift key and any number (depending on what diacritic I wanted). For some reason, at some point this stopped working. Does anyone have any insight as to how to fix it? I've scoured the internet and found nothing.